# Yii2 form checkbox template

Tags: forms, templates, checkbox, yii2

I set the form parameters:

```
<?
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'activeForm',
    'action' => 'javascript://',
]);

$checkboxTemplate = '<div class="checkbox">{labelTitle}{beginLabel}{input}<span class="slider round"></span>{endLabel}{error}{hint}</div>';
echo $form->field($aclForm, tbl_RbacActions::IS_DEVELOPMENT)
    ->checkbox([
        'labelOptions' => ['class' => 'switch'],
        'template' => $checkboxTemplate
]);
?>
```

As a result, it still turns a standard form with standart classes:

```
<form id="Index-form" class="row col-12 no-gutters" action="javascript://" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf-frontend" value="Lo7lVHTJ9wcN5rdfjK-b7AgW8L4OHEaqI9IsVofZPOl3yKkFBJqAQz-i-y7H3-mdMUmY-H1RcMRBhkU01-F2oA==">
    <div class="form-group field-aclform-is_development required">
        <input type="hidden" name="AclForm[is_development]" value="0">
        <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" id="aclform-is_development" name="AclForm[is_development]" value="1" template="{input}{beginLabel}{labelTitle}{endLabel}{error}"> Is Development</label>
        <div class="help-block"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Why is it adding the template as the input attribute?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You haven't provided the `HTML` template that you are trying to follow or integrate here in the checkbox, but regarding the `template` being added as the `attribute` of the input field is quite logical as you are passing it as the option of the [`checkbox`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activefield#checkbox()-detail) rather than the [`field`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activeform#field()-detail) option.

You need to provide the `template` as an array to the third parameter `option` of the `field` see below

```
<?php
    $form = ActiveForm::begin(
        [
            'id' => 'activeForm',
            'action' => 'javascript://'
        ]
    );

    $checkboxTemplate = '<div class="checkbox">{labelTitle}{beginLabel}{input}<span class="slider round"></span>{endLabel}{error}{hint}</div>';

    echo $form->field(
        $aclForm, 
        tbl_RbacActions::IS_DEVELOPMENT, 
        [
            'template' => $checkboxTemplate
        ]
    )->checkbox(
        [
            'labelOptions' => ['class' => 'switch']

        ]
    );
```

Comment: figured it out, Thanks Muhammad; I need to switch the ActiveForm from widget to bootstrap

`//use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;`
`use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;`